# Django Update values in a dictionary built from a model

Tags: python, django, dictionary

After I've loaded all of the objects of a model into a dictionary, how can I update all of the values associated with a curtain field in the model? I'm trying to update the dictionary, not the model. For instance, here is my dictionary, `objects = Liquor.objects.all()` , one of that model's fields is 'BrandName', how can I update all the values in the dictionary associated with the BrandName key? More specifically, I want the value to go from just listing the brand name, to listing `<a href='Object ID'>BrandName</a>`?

Comment: Liquor.objects.all() will return a queryset i.e. a list of objects of Liquor model.

Do you have a list of dicts with each dict representing an object of Liquor model?

Answer (score -1):

Use multiple updates.

```
Liquor.objects.filter(some_field='BrandName').update(some_field='<a href='Object ID'>BrandName</a>')
```

Comment: First of all, I have far too many Brand Names to just use multiple updates, second of all, BrandName IS my field name, third of all, this updates the data in the database, I don't want to do that, I want to update it in the dictionary.